# Question related to ellipses and their properties

Tags: analysis, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I was solving this question related to ellipses but got stuck, please help me in angle chasing:

Could not even move further :

> Consider the ellipse $4x^2+y^2-8x+4y+4=0.$ Pair of tangents $PT_1$ and $PT_2$ are drawn to the ellipse from $P(-8,-2).$ Let $S_1'$ be the image of $S_1$ about $PT_1$ and $S_2'$ be the image of $S_2$ about $PT_2$, then if $\angle PS_1S_2'=\alpha$ and $\angle PS_1'S_2=\beta$, then $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ is equal to $\ldots$? ($S_1, S_2$ refer to the foci of the ellipse.)

My progress in an image:
[image]

I only want mathematical and rigorous proofs as it is also very much self-evident to me that  and  equal by symmetry .

Comment: Please refrain from using pictures. There are [different reasons](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/1273570) for that, for example, the search function doesn’t see them. Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead. Unfortunately, your post doesn’t fully meet this site’s policy (see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)). I recommend that you edit your post. Most importantly, please tell in the post, what progress did you achieve while solving?

Comment: Thank you @Davide

Comment: Can you edit some more ?

Comment: If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the foci, aren't $\alpha$ and $\beta$ equal by symmetry?

Comment: Sir I want a proof which is mathematical and rigorous

Comment: Reflecting everything about $y=-2$, the points $P,S_2,S_1’$ get reflected to $P,S_1,S_2’$ respectively. But reflection can’t change angles. So the two given angles are equal.

Comment: Symmetry is a mathematical and rigorous thing.

Comment: Still I insist can this be shown using equations ?

Comment: @AayushSethia if symmetry doesn’t please you, then you can work out the coordinates of $S_1,S_1’,S_2,S_2’$ and then find the two angles (using the suitable slopes) and see that they are equal. However this is useless in essence. Could you elaborate why symmetry appears non-rigorous to you?

Comment: I wanted to know some theorem like any basic or advanced which is better than just looking and telling that the angles are equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those looking for the easier answer :

Told to me by someone :

$PS_1 =PS_2$

$PS_1 ^{'} = PS_2 ^{'}$

$PS_1 = PS_1 ^{'}$(Congruent triangles) , $PS_2 = PS_2^{'}$

Now $S_1S_2^{'} = 2a$, as $S_1S_2^{'} = S_2^{'}T_2 + S_1T_2$ (Property that $S_2^{'} ,T_2$ and $S_1$ are collinear)

$S_2^{'}T_2 = S_2T_2$

$S_1S_2^{'} = S_2T_2 + S_2T_2 =2a$

$S_2S_1^{'} = 2a $

Now we can say that by congruent triangles

Both angles are equal